# Storing part of a command string as a variable in bash

Tags: bash, command, string-interpolation

I am using a variable to combine commands:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    cmd=$(sudo -i -u $domain wp --path=$path)
    $cmd post create --post_type=page --post_status=publish --post_title='Page1'
    $cmd post create --post_type=page --post_status=publish --post_title='Page110'
    $cmd widget delete $($cmd widget list sidebar-1 --format=ids)
```

edit1: example using cmd='sudo -i -u $domain wp --path=$path';echo $cmd |bash

```
    #!/bin/bash
    cmd='sudo -i -u $domain wp --path=$path'
    echo $cmd --post_type=page --post_status=publish --post_title='Page1'|bash

    echo $cmd widget delete $(echo $cmd widget list sidebar-1 --format=ids|bash)|bash
```

I get an error when trying to do the above. I've tried using `'single quotes'` and `"double quotes"` instead of `(parenthesis)`, but it won't work.

I understand that I can just put in a temp variable and replace when I finish, but I really would like to know how to combine commands in bash.

edit2: created a simple version to test the suggested answer on:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpcmd="history| grep "
echo "$tmpcmd ls"|bash
```

the output is: blank

Comment: cmd=$(command) sets variable cmd to the output of the command executed.

Comment: As above and ... you may want `cmd="sudo -i -u $domain wp --path=$path"` but constructions like you have included above are ripe for hard to decipher problems. Good luck.

Comment: Please add a shebang and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Storing commands (or parts of them) in variables tends not to work well except for simple cases, and is best avoided. Variables are for storing data, not executable code. See [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store all commands as strings, omitting '$(...)', with runs the command `...` and returns its STDOUT (not what you want).
Then use `echo "$cmd1 $cmd2 ..." | bash` to execute the resulting command in the shell. The double quotes around all commands are important, to prevent treating some of the strings as the options to `echo`:

```
cmd1='command 1 string'
cmd2='command 2 string'

# Execute: command 1 string command 2 string
echo "$cmd1 $cmd2" | bash
```

Example 1:

```
cmd1='sudo'
cmd2='purge'

# Runs: sudo purge
echo "$cmd1 $cmd2" | bash
```

Example 2:

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmpcmd="( echo 'foo' ; echo 'bar' ) | grep"
echo "with variable interpolation:"
echo "$tmpcmd 'foo'" | bash
echo "without variable interpolation:"
echo "( echo 'foo' ; echo 'bar' ) | grep 'foo'" | bash
echo "original command:"
( echo 'foo' ; echo 'bar' ) | grep 'foo'
echo 'done'
```

Output is identical regardless of whether the command was or was not interpolated and whether or not it was executed as is:

```
with variable interpolation:
foo
without variable interpolation:
foo
original command:
foo
done
```

Example 4 (based on the example by the OP, confirmed that it does not work as some expect):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ls > /dev/null
tmpcmd="history | grep"
echo "with variable interpolation:"
echo "$tmpcmd ls" | bash
echo "without variable interpolation:"
echo "history | grep ls" | bash
echo "original command:"
history | grep ls
echo 'done'
```

Output:

```
with variable interpolation:
without variable interpolation:
original command:
done
```

Example 4 does not print any output from the `history` commands **because bash disables history in non-interactive shells by default**. It is best not to use `history` in such shell script examples. See also:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5684/13411
https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112354/13411

Comment: hmmm, so this may not be ideal when there are multiple unique occurrences.

If I could get a variable to run bash<echo "$cmd" rest-of-command args then maybe..

Comment: Fixed typos, sorry.

Comment: @stackmacstacky Could you please clarify? An specific example would help. Best if you edit the question - this way everyone can be on the same page.

Comment: added what happens when I do the suggested. returns blank

Comment: I'd recommend against this approach, as it opens up all sorts of ways to get the quoting and escaping wrong (very similar to the ways `eval` can go wrong).